# Definition of Primary Decomposition

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

When encountered with the word 'decomposition', we immediately think of a structure being broken down into and written as a (kind of) 'union' of simpler parts(say for example the decomposition of a number into its prime factors).

But, primary decomposition is described in terms of 'intersection'. (Statement: A primary decomposition of an ideal $I$ in $R$ is the expression of $I$ as a finite intersection of primary ideals)

Is the nomenclature of this phenomenon as a 'decomposition' marely a coincidence? Or is it in line with what is traditionally meant by a decomposition?

Comment: I think it's interesting you use decomposition of a number into a product of primes as an example of something that's like a union. The ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by an integer $n$ is the intersection of the ideals generated by the pure prime powers. In this way, primary decomposition is very much like decomposition into prime factors to me